# rich:tooltip does not work in rich:popupPanel

Tags: jsf, richfaces

When I attach rich:tooltip element to any element of the screen of rich:popupPanel, it shows nothing. How can I solve this problem?

```
                <rich:popupPanel id="balancePopup" width="800" resizeable="false"
                    rendered="true" autosized="true" modal="true"domElementAttachment="body">
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="balancePanelRegion">
                        <ui:include src="popup.xhtml" />
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </rich:popupPanel>
```

This doesn't work (popup.xhtml)

```
                        <h:inputText value=""
                            id="my" styleClass="input-medium" readonly="true">
                            <rich:tooltip id="tooltip"><span>Hint</span></rich:tooltip>
                        </h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing z-index of tooltip component solved the problem:

```
    <rich:tooltip id="tooltip3" style="z-index:10000;">Tooltip</rich:tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `rich:tooltip` outside:

```
<h:outputText value="Test"/>
<h:panelGroup id="inputWithTooltip">
    <h:inputText />
    <rich:tooltip mode="client" layout="block">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.info}" escape="false"/>
    </rich:tooltip>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Nothing changed. I think it is because of the popup screen opens lightbox style, it can be a bug of Richfaces